# Connection closes when I run ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, connection, database-connection, connection-string

I know, the question may seem pretty elementary, but still I cannot find a single answer to it.
My ASP.NET MVC application connects to the database, DB First. The connection string is written inside the web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="GunSudexDbContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.GunSudexDbContext.csdl|res://*/Models.GunSudexDbContext.ssdl|res://*/Models.GunSudexDbContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\GunSudex.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <!--<add name="GunSudexDbContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.GunSudexDbContext.csdl|res://*/Models.GunSudexDbContext.ssdl|res://*/Models.GunSudexDbContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS; attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\GunSudex.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />-->
  </connectionStrings>
```

When I load my solution, the connection is not shown in Server Explorer, but appears as soon as I refresh it. Server Explorer shows that the connection is open. It may close quite fast -- in several seconds, and it requires to be reloaded. When I run my application (even if Server Explorer shows that the connection is open) the exception is thrown on the line of first query to the database. So I suppose the connection closes (yes, the application loads quite long). 
What's the problem and how can I fix it? Should I check my connection inside the code?
Thanks in advance for your time and efforts.
EDIT:
as Fleshy asked, I use Entity Framework. I create a static context variable in my base controller, but get the exception in one of the methods of this controller.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of server explorer, you must still manage opening (and closing) your database connection in code. You haven't said whether you are using an ORM (Entity Framework etc.)...more info would be helpful.

Comment: Can you post the exception, please.